# Accessing bound data from a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net Web project and I want to add a GridView, which I have done.  I have tried binding it to an ObjectDataSource and in Code behind and both work fine.  I am binding to a table that has 8 columns of which I want to show 3 and in the OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler I want to retrieve the bound record and populate detail controls but when I look at the rows dataitem it is null and the cells contain only the data that I have elected to show in the grid.  I know there's got to be a way but I've searched for hours and I'm probably just not entering the right search criteria but I'm stumped.

```
<div class="help-control-wrapper">
    <div class="help-control-header">
    </div>
    <div class="help-control-detail">
        <table id="Table1" class="t1" summary="" runat="server">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="help-control-grid">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#DDEEFF"
                    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">

                    <rowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"  
                        forecolor="DarkBlue"
                        font-italic="true"
                        height="16px"/> 

                    <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="PaleTurquoise"  
                        forecolor="DarkBlue"
                        font-italic="true"
                        height="16px"/>               
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommentID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentName" HeaderText="Context" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommentorName" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommentorEmail" HeaderText="Email" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CommentDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllComments"
    TypeName="CommentService">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

then in the code behind

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");

            PopulateItem();
        }
        else
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem is that you need to get the data from Hidden gridview Cell ?

Comment: I tried different things to try and get this to work.
Like I said I have 8 columns of which 2 of them are IDs and I don't want to see those columns but I want the information to be available.  I tried a hidden field and it didn't work, I tried using a column but setting visibility to false.  It appears if it's not visible it's not available?  The information has to be somewhere I just haven't found out where.

Comment: There is always arrays. Sometimes controls of asp.net will be unusable when they have "Visible = false"